# Finding new Block

Tags: blockchain, block, protocol, mining-theory

I need to know how miners try to find the next block hash... First, they choose list of transactions to be included in the block, calculate [Merkle Root], set current Timestamp, then start Nonce=1 and calculate the hash.

My questions are:

1. are they get a new Timestamp for each time they increase the Nonce value?
2. The list of transactions they chose don't change for each Nonce value?
3. How they calculate the tx id for the reward transaction?
4. Do the include the tx of the reward transaction in the top of the chosen list of transaction?
5. Where from they get the current Timestamp.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

> are they get a new Timestamp for each time they increase the Nonce value?

No, they wouldn't bother changing both at once usually, just the nonce and/or the extra data in the coinbase transaction.

> The list of transactions they chose don't change for each Nonce value?

Changing the list of transactions every time would require the merkle root to be recalculated every time which would be a lot slower and pointless, so no

> How they calculate the tx id for the reward transaction?

Same way the TXID is calculated for any other transaction

> Do the include the tx of the reward transaction in the top of the chosen list of transaction?

Yes, the coinbase transaction is always the first transaction in the block

> Where from they get the current Timestamp.

Probably from their system time on their machine or similar I would imagine, it doesn't really matter